# How to know which tag to apply "plot explanation" or "analysis"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have found that there are alot similar questions that ask for better understanding of the plot and some of them use "plot explanation" tag while others use "analysis" tag. The tag info says what they are for, but they still have very similar usage.

How to know when to use "plot explanation" and when "analysis" tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From plot-explanation:

> Seeking to understand a story plot better, or to clear up confusion
>   about certain aspects or plot points.

From analysis:

> Understanding the underlying concepts and themes behind the
>   film/TV-show and its different interpretations. Not to be used for
>   direct plot discussions.

Plot-explanation are for questions that just clarify the what happened in a film.  Analysis tends to go deeper, digging into themes prevalent in the movie and WHY characters make certain decisions.

A REALLY good example of an analysis question is Ankit's question: [What was the significance of Northern cardinal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65911/what-was-the-significance-of-northern-cardinal).  He noticed a recurring piece in the movie that isn't explicitly explained in the movie, leading to a deeper level of questions about WHY that was included and what it represented.

A REALLY good example of plot-explanation is [What really happened in Memento?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/what-really-happened-in-memento).  This movie is very confusing and doesn't follow a linear plot, so asking what the actual order of events is makes perfect sense for this sort of movie.